# Java: Read a text file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, text

I've a txt file composed by two  columns like this:

```
Name1     _     Opt1
Name2     _     Opt2
Name3     _     Opt3
```

In each row there's a name, a tab delimiter, a _ and then another name; there are really many rows (about 150000) and i'm not even sure which one is the best constructor to use, i'm thinking about a two dimensional array but it could be also something else if it's a better choice. For me it's important that i can access to the elements with something like this a[x][y].
I've done this but i just know how to count the number of the lines or how to put each lines in a different position of an array.
Here's the code:

```
int countLine = 0;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            reader.close();
            break;
        } else {
            countLine++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "For me it's important that i can access to the elements with something like this a[x][y]. I've done this...". Did you already create your 2d array or is that what you're asking help on? The "I've done this" confuses things. You will have to separate out the "namex" and the "optx" using the delimiter.

Comment: It's unclear what you really want to ask.

Comment: i don't know how to take the "name" of the line and put in the position a[x+1][y] of an array and than put the "opt" in the position a[x][y+1].

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know the number of lines ahead of time, I would use an `ArrayList` instead of an array. The splitting of lines into String values can easily be done with a regular expression.

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)\t_\t(.*)");
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
int countLine = 0;

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
while (true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        reader.close();
        break;
    } else {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            list.add(new String[] { matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2) });
        }
        countLine++;
    }
```

Comment: The `countLine` is not needed as the same info is already present in `list.size()` but I like your suggestion of using the regular expression.

Comment: @5gon12eder The `countLine` part was just copied from the original question. The difference between its value and `list.size()` -- at least in my code -- is that the latter only gives you the number of *matching* lines. If all lines match, the value will be the same as `countLine`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Whether or not that info is wanted.

Comment: this solution looks great! but i've a problem in: 
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
it says that List type is not generic and cannot be parameterized with the arguments <Strings[]>. I'm trying to solve it but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Art_Knopfler Make sure you're importing `java.util.List` and not, say, `java.awt.List`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to write a class that represents an entry in your file.  It could be quite sophisticated but a really simple design will probably also do.

```
class Record {

    final String name;
    final String option;

    Record(final String name, final String option) {
        this.name = name;
        this.option = option;
    }
}
```

Using this class is much better than messing with arrays of strings.

The second thing to do is to use a more abstract data structure than an array structure to put your records into.  This will free you from the burden of having to know the number of elements in advance.  I recommend that you use an `ArrayList` for this.  Then, you can read in one record at a time and add it to your collection.

```
List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
records.add(new Record("NameX", "OptionX"));
System.out.printf("There are %d records in the list.%n", records.size());
```

Of course, the second line in the above example should be done over and over again in your loop that reads the lines of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data on

HashMap>

The first String (key) is your name
The second String (key) is your opt and his value (reault) is the object result.

You can use it as:

result = youHashMap.get(name).get(opt);

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList instead of array because the size is unknown. Use Scanner to read file, and to check existence of next line in file use hasNextLine() method,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int countline = 0;
        Scanner inp=new Scanner(new File("/home/nasir/Desktop/abc.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

        while(inp.hasNextLine()){
            list.add(inp.nextLine());// adding a row in ArrayList
            countline++;// counting every line/row
        }

        System.out.println(countline+" "+list.get(2));
    }// Main
}// Class
```