# select string in text with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Hi I've a text file build like this:

```
1   name1   _   opt1    _    no1    _    no2   
3   name2   _   opt2    _    no3    _    no4
2   name3   _   opt3    _    no5    _    no6
```

I've to select just nameX and optX from every row. The text is tab separated between first and second columns and between others columns there's also a _ between the two tabs delimiter.
I'm able to select `"X   nameX   _   optX"`, but i don't want to select also the number and the tab divisor before nameX. The regular expression that i use is: `"\\.*\t_\t\\.*"`

Here the java code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listDic = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    int countLine = 0;

    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            reader.close();
            break;
        } else {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\.*\t_\t\\.*");

            listDic.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            listDic.get(countLine).add(0, s.next());
            System.out.println(listDic.get(countLine).get(i));
            // System.out.println(listDic.get(i));

            listDic.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            listDic.get(countLine).add(1, s.next());
            System.out.println(listDic.get(countLine).get(i));
            // System.out.println(listDic.get(countLine));

            countLine++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Also, don't forget to close your Scanner when done using it meaning at the end of (but inside of) the else block.

Comment: What you need is a positive lookbehind.  Check the Javadoc for the `Pattern` class.

Comment: You could have just adapted my answer to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29037148/261142) by using a different regexp, e.g., `[0-9]+\t([^\t]*)\t_\t([^\t]*)\t.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- Your delimiter string needs adjustment (see below).  It should account for the fact that there's always one tab and sometimes an underscore followed by a second tab.
- You likely did not mean to create the `ArrayList` twice.
- You can skip the first token read by the scanner by simply calling `next()` again.
- The variable `i` was undefined here; I suppose this code is cut/pasted from somewhere using a loop.

Perhaps something like this would suit you:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listDic = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

for (int countLine = 0;; countLine++) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        reader.close();
        break;
    }

    Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
    s.useDelimiter("\t(_\t)?");

    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.next(); // Skip the first token
    tokens.add(s.next());  // Take the second token (name)
    tokens.add(s.next());  // Take the third token (opt)
    listDic.add(tokens);

    System.out.println(listDic.get(countLine).get(0));
    System.out.println(listDic.get(countLine).get(1));
}
```

Comment: thanks Arthur (you've my same name), it works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks, Arthur!  Feel free to mark my response as the answer, if it works for you.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for:

```
String[] tokens = line.split("\t_\t");
```

For example:

```
String string = "2\tname3\t_\topt3\t_\tno5\t_\tno6";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.split("\t_\t")));
```

produces:

```
[2  name3, opt3, no5, no6]
```

If you want to split by tabs *or* `"\t_\t"`, you might use `"[\t_]+"` as your split.